# How to make FAB animate out when removing it?

Tags: dart, flutter

I know that there is an animation for `FloatingActionButton`'s animating out (what I mean by that is that when the FAB disappears, it e.g. gets smaller).
In my case I have a *FAB* placed like this:

```
Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: SomeBuilder(builder:
    () => someCondition ? FloatingActionButton() : Container()),
  ...
)
```

In that case the `FloatingActionButton` has **no animation** when `someCondition` changes to display the `Container`.
When navigating to a different route the *`FloatingActionButton` in the code* does animate to represent the position and shape of the other `FloatingActionButton` in the other route, which is how I know that the Hero Animations are generally working.

Is there any additional step I need to take to make the ***FAB*** have an animation when it is replaced by a `Container`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FloatingButton leave animation plays out when you set `floatingActionButton` to null or when the new root widget has a different `key`.

Therefore the correct way to play the leave animation in this situation is:

```
floatingActionButton: someCondition ?
    SomeBuilder(
      builder: () =>
        new FloatingActionButton(),
    )
    : null
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The example is useless though because it has nothing to do with the use case I proposed, i.e. I do not change state of the parent widget of `Scaffold`.

Comment: In your example, that's the Scaffold which holds your `someCondition` though. I just respected that

Comment: Not necessarily, but anyway: Do you that there is a way to play the animation without rebuilding my whole `Scaffold`?

Comment: I doubt you can. As you'd have the parent layout depending on the child layout. There are some solutions to it, but I don't know your use-case. Do you mind explaining it a bit more?